# Why doesn't React-Router show the links?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've been trying React-Router for the first time and I tried to write some code, but the links don't seem to work. These are my links. At first the links worked, when I put them in the App-Component. Then I tried to put the Navigation into it's own component and then the links didn't work. Thank you for your help!

```
import React from "react";
import About from "./About";
import Home from "./Home";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Navigation />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing `import { BrowserRouter as Link } from "react-router-dom";`

It should be `import { Link } from "react-router-dom";`